# Saying it from the heart

Tags: phrase-usage

> I'm saying it from the heart.

> I don't say things off a script, I say them from the heart.

Does "say something from the heart" work instead of "saying something from the bottom of the heart"?

And can I switch that "the" out with "my"?

> I'm saying it from my heart.

Answer (score 1):

They are similar so I think are mostly interchangeable. There may be a slight subtle difference. I think "said from the heart" is used usually after a meaningful speech/ proclamation/ personal declaration/ literary piece.

"Meant from the bottom of my heart" could be used for even more emphasis and sounds a bit more personal and everyday.
It features in Stevie Wonder 's song.

To say something from the heart is when you say something you really mean or feel.
Example: What I said in my poem was said from the heart.
They are not anyone else's thoughts/ feelings but my own very deep and real ones. So, if someone says," just say it from the heart". They mean say what you really mean or feel.
It is  normally used as a set phrase, so we usually use,"say  it from THE heart." It is normally referenced as a past or recent past event e.g. he said it from the heart or it was said from the heart.
Occasionally, you could replace it with" My "or "Your" but this is less common.

We usually, say, I MEAN it from the bottom of my heart.
Example. When I said I loved you , I meant it from the bottom of my heart.
In other words, I was telling the truth. It implies deep feelings either good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

**[from the heart](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/straight-from-the-heart)** means being sincere, or being completely honest about your feelings.

When we add **deep** about feelings, we generally refer to something that is [strongly felt](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deep), so "from the bottom of my  heart" could just mean "very sincerely".

In this case, it can also mean that you are referring to deeply held feelings, rather than superficial ones. For example, if a man says "I love you" simply because a woman is attractive, that is superficial. If a man says "I love you" because he admires and respects a woman, knows and accepts her faults, finds her attractive, and could never imagine being without her, he is speaking from the bottom of his heart.